# Windows socket asm: context stack is empty

Tags: assembly, nasm, winsock2

Hello I have problem with structure while compiling my asm code with NASM.

This is my structure definition and declaration:

```
struc wsa_data_struct
    .wVersion resw 1
    .wHighVersion resw 1
    .szDescription resb WSADESCRIPTION_LEN
    .szSystemStatus resb WSASYS_STATUS_LEN
    .iMaxSckets resw 1
    .ImaxUdpDg resw 1
    .lpVendorInfo resb 1
    .size
endstruc

wsa_dat:
    istruc
        at wsa_data_struct.wVersion, dw 0
        at wsa_data_struct.wHighVersion, dw 0
        at wsa_data_struct.szDescription, db 0
        at wsa_data_struct.szSystemStatus, db 0
        at wsa_data_struct.iMaxSckets, dw 0
        at wsa_data_struct.ImaxUdpDg, dw 0
        at wsa_data_struct.lpVendorInfo, db 0
    iend
```

and when i try compile my code this error pop up:

```
error: (at:1) `%$strucname': context stack is empty
error: (at:1) `%$strucstart': context stack is empty
error: (at:1) `%$strucname': context stack is empty
error: (at:1) `%$strucstart': context stack is empty
error: (at:1) `%$strucname': context stack is empty
error: (at:1) `%$strucstart': context stack is empty
.
.
.
```

this is just for first line of declaration of strucuture and it goes on for each line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`istruc` needs the name of the structure:

```
istruc wsa_data_struct
```

See: http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc4.html#section-4.12.11

BTW: `.size` needs a type like `resd 1`.